# ruby regex to find nested matches

Tags: ruby, regex-greedy, non-greedy

My regex is

```
/a .*programming .*test .*this/i
```

and test string is

```
This is a test This is a programming test This is a programming test in any language
```

The match I'm getting is

```
a test This is a programming test This
```

But there is another shorter match **"a programming test This"** , which this regex is unable to find , i used scan method to find all the matches but that even can not capture this .

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegexP is a very complex thing! You really need to know which parts of your string are critical to match and which arent. There are tons of ways to accomplish a match, but it's not easy to guess what you ACTUALLY want:

```
s = "This is a test This is a programming test This is a programming test in any language"
s.match(/a [^a]*programming .*test .*this/i)[0]
 => "a programming test This"
```